# Oz Mozart factorial function

Tags: oz, mozart

I have this factorial function that is currently working, but the result I'm having is not the one I need.

The code is:

```
declare
fun {Fact N}
if N==1 then [N]
  else
    Out={Fact N-1}in
     N*Out.1|Out end
end
{Browse {Fact 4}}
```

The result is : `[24,6,2,1]` but I need that the result shows: `[1,2,6,24]` and I can't see where the error is.

Answer (score 3):

You want to decrement N, having no other argument than N.
But there is a problem:

- a list `[1 2 6 24]` can actually be written as `'|'(1 '|'(2 '|'(6 '|'(24 nil))))` in oz
  so at the first or last call, your function has to return `24|nil`...
  However, your function can not know if one call is the first call or the last, as you don't have any parameter.
- your function is not tail recursive (if you use a book to learn oz, you'll discover why, and why it's bad)

Here is the best function I can think of:

```
declare
fun {Fact N}
   fun{Aux N Nmax FactNminus1}
      if N>Nmax then nil
      else (FactNminus1*N)|{Aux N+1 Nmax FactNminus1*N}
      end
   end
in
   {Aux 1 N 1}
end
{Browse {Fact 4}}
```

- N is increment until Nmax
- FactNminus1 contain the {Fact N-1} so you don't have to compute it each time.

Comment: Thanks!! your explanation was very useful to see that I was not creating a tail recursive function, and I'm taking a look to one book to learn more about oz.